# Custom Logout not working in Napili Community?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, napili, menu

I have configured a Custom Menu on the header component on my Community(Napili template) using lightning:buttonMenu and had Logout as one of the menu items. Clicking on it, it would then redirect to a page(I call it as Logout screen).

```
if(selectedMenuItemValue == 'Logout'){
       var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
         urlEvent.setParams({
             "url": '/logout' 
         });
         urlEvent.fire();
```

But how can I actually implement a Logout that happens from Standard Logout item from Community's default **Profile Header**?

Comment: Use "/secur/logout.jsp"

Also if navigateToURL is not working then have a simple <a href> link and construct the ULR like this:
SalesforceOrgURL+CommunityPrefix+'/secur/logout.jsp'

Good idea is to keep the Org and Community in the custom label and construct them in the component as:

<a href="{!$Label.c.OrgURL+'/'+$Label.c.Community_Prefix+'/'+'secur/logout.jsp'}"
Logout
</a>

Comment: I am afraid it didn't worked. It said: **Invalid Page**. What I did was, changed the url in my code to yours. (< _ >)

Comment: Can you please provide the code snippet? I am doing exactly the same and its working

Comment: Oh I missed your new edit. Let me try that and get back to you soon.

Comment: @JaiChaturvedi As I mentioned, Logout is one of the menu items `<lightning:menuItem>`  under `<lightning:buttonMenu>`. I couldn't use a `<a href>` tag as its not working with buttonMenu tag. Is there any other work around? Thanks

Comment: Never mind, it worked by just replacing the URL with **SalesforceOrgURL+/secur/logout.jsp**, i.e, `"url": 'SalesforceOrgURL+/secur/logout.jsp'`. Thanks for your help. Could you please add this as an answer? I would make it MARKED. \m/

Comment: I just observed one issue, after clicking on **Logout**, it is going to another tab and getting me logout. But the community tab remains open(without logging out), and after I refresh it, it is logging-off. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Arnold please add the latest code to help you fix your issue

Comment: `if(selectedMenuItemValue == 'Logout'){
           var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
             urlEvent.setParams({
                 "url": 'https://arnoldjr.cs17.my.salesforce.com/secur/logout.jsp' 
             });
             urlEvent.fire();`.

This is the latest code snippet which I am using, causing another issue, I mentioned in my previous comment(logout in another tab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `window.location.href=salesforceurl/secure/logout.jsp`

This will use the current window to navigate to logout url

Comment: Cool. Working as I desired. Thank you for that. I would also appreciate @JaiChaturvedi for providing me insight on the possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can also add additional parameter like:

```
window.location.href=<salesforce-url>/secure/logout.jsp?retUrl=http://google.com'
```

to redirect the user to home page of your application after successful logout.

Comment: I used this approach in my lightning component's controller. It logged out, but it didn't redirect to google. Is there any other approach to do the redirection?